# javascript regex recognation in a html string

Tags: html, regex

I'm using this regex to parse urls:

```
var urlRegex = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
```

but when I have something like that into the text:

```
<img scr="http://blog.bnf.fr/uploads/lecteurs/2012/10/nouvelles_images.jpg" />
```

problems happens... I was thinking in avoid string that starts with quotes, but I'was not able to put this condition in that regex expression.

could someone help-me?

here I have the full example: https://jsfiddle.net/j0mnL1h4/1/

Comment: escape all the forward slashes.

Comment: Raj, I don't get yout point... why should I escape the slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix... this is the final result:

```
(^|(?<=[ >\n]))[^"'][a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```